# How do I pick up a design displayed on the ground?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

[image: Display on Ground]

I made the mistake of placing a design pattern on the ground. How do I pick it back up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to walk over it and press “Y” :)

Comment: Oof ;) Thank you! (I could have sworn I did that, but perhaps while standing atop it, rather than to its side.)